# Run Heroku TypeScript buildpack locally

Tags: node.js, heroku, typescript, buildpack

I'm building NodeJS app and deploy it on Heroku. This works great.
Now I want to write the application with TypeScript. To do that I'm using [pk11/heroku-buildpack-typescript](https://github.com/pk11/heroku-buildpack-typescript)

My question is how to run this buildpack locally during development?